# Actions on Google and Account linking failure after tokens returned

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google, google-home

Trying to test auth in the Web Simulator using the OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow, https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator

See: https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/testing#testing_account_linking_with_google_home_web_simulator

And:
https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/oauth2-code-flow

Provided you've setup your Action to require authorization against your authorization service, when you try to access your Action the Assistant advises you that you need to Link your account.
In the same response the simulator provides a URL for initiating the linking process, see:

```
"debugInfo": {
    "sharedDebugInfo": [
        {
            "name": "Account Linking Url",
            "debugInfo": "https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=your-google-project-id_dev&scopes=your-scopes&return_url=https://www.google.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Calling this URL (paste into a browser) will take you through an OAuth2 flow, assuming the user actions required are successful Google will call your token endpoint with the authorization code provided during the flow.

But then I was getting:

```
result_code=FAILURE&result_message=Account+linking+failed
```

It all appeared to be working from my side but Google was returning a FAILURE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, my token endpoint was returning my standard token response object, which included an **access_token**, a **refresh_token**, an **expires_in**, a **session_state** and another token that wasn't needed for this purpose but was standard to my token response.

And when I tested this same response on Googles playground it was fine:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

But not so when using the Assistant URL:
https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=your-google-project-id_dev&scopes=your-scopes&return_url=https://www.google.com/

The reason it turns out is that the Assistant does not like superfluous properties in the response object.

I have yet to fully establish what is and isn't allowed but so far you can have:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token: "xxx",
    "refresh_token": "yyy",
    "expires_in": "zzz"
}
```

With these I now get:

```
result_code=SUCCESS
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. Are you sure its because of the extra fields in the response object? 
In my case I am using keycloak for implementation of authorization code flow. I can't think of a way to modify the response by discarding the extra information.

Comment: @iwekesi in my case extra fields were definitely the problem, if your auth flow works in the playground (see answer) and not in Assistant then this could be your issue too

Comment: as you said, that is exactly the issue! Thanks a lot for figuring out and letting us know.

Comment: I am little curious as to why can't google ignore the "superfluous properties". That seems very funny.

Comment: I spoke to a google developer at GoogleIO about this, he said they are working on replacing the systems behind this auth flow.

Comment: Also, expires_in should not be a string, but an integer. So no quotes around the value.